# How to make one line for loop in android shell

Tags: android, bash, shell, sh

This works on bash

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done
```

the out put is
1
2
3
4
5
But on android shell
the output is 
{1..5}

Answer (score 11):

```
i=0; while [ $(($i)) -le 5 ]; do i=$(($i + 1)); echo $i; done;
```

Tested on adb shell in Galaxy Tab 4 7"  -- Thanks to Lynch for most of the answer.  'expr fails in default shell.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried,

```
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++)) do echo $i; done
```

**Edit-**

or you can use sequence,

```
for i in `seq 1 5`; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: What you've mentioned is a `bash` construct.  If brace expansion didn't work, then this would never work/

Comment: Neither the double parentheses nor the seq function work on my default Android ADB shell.

Answer (score 5):

If your sequence isn't too large, you can just list out the values of interest. So in the default Android ADB shell:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done

Returns:
1
2
3
```

or:

```
for i in 5 11 7; do echo $i; done

Returns:
5
11
7
```

or even:

```
for i in apple orange banana; do echo $i; done

Returns:
apple
orange
banana
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  It's not pretty to list out 30 numbers like I need to but it works, and it's faster than beating my head at the wall looking for the perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

If your shell is sh then use the following command:

```
for i in `seq 1 5`; do echo $i; done
```

**Edit**

You probably dont have the `seq` program. Try this command instead:

```
i=1; while [ $i -le 5 ] ; do echo $i; i=`expr $i + 1`; done
```

Comment: The seq function doesn't work on my default Android ADB shell.